# Powershell - Double dropdown menu selection

Tags: powershell, drop-down-menu

I'm using a dropdown menu for one of my script and I call it twice to get two differents value on two different windows. I want to optimize my script and create one windows with two dropdown box in the same windows.

Look at my script:

```
    $DropDownArray = "Value1" , "Value2" , "Value3"


    # Form building

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.width = 300
    $Form.height = 200
    $Form.Text = ”User move Original Location Box”
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"


    $DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,10)
    $DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

    ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
    $DropDown.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null
    }

    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

    $DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
    $DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,200)
    $DropDownLabel.Text = "Select the user Original location ?"
    $Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)


    $OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
    $OKButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.Add_Click({
    $Form.DialogResult = "OK"
    $Form.close()
    })
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)


    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,75)
    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({
    $Form.DialogResult = "Cancel"
    $Form.close()
    })
    $Form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


    $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})

    $result = $Form.ShowDialog()

    if($result -eq "OK")
    {
    $SrcServer = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
    }
    else
    {
    $SrcServer = $null
    }
foreach( $Site in $SiteAttribute.location.Site){
   $var1 = $Site.city    
    If ($var1 -match $SrcServer){
            $SOURCE = $site.server
            $OldSiteGroup = $site.OldSiteGroup
            $OldDFSGroup = $site.OldDFSGroup
            $NewDFSRemote = $site.NewDFSRemote
       } 

}                                                             

$source

# Form building

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 300
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = ”User move Destination Location”
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"


$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,10)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
$DropDown.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,200)
$DropDownLabel.Text = "Select the user Destination location ?"
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)


$OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$OKButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({
$Form.DialogResult = "OK"
$Form.close()
})
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)


$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,75)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({
$Form.DialogResult = "Cancel"
$Form.close()
})
$Form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})

$result = $Form.ShowDialog()

if($result -eq "OK")
{
$DestServer = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
}
else
{
$DestServer = $null
}
#The Variable $Sharelocalpath is use in "Part 2 Creating a share on a remote computer" to help WMI
#to create the shared folder remotly using the Localserver Path to create the share if not the good value the U: drive will not map.

foreach( $Site in $SiteAttribute.location.Site){
   $var2 = $Site.city    
    If ($var2 -match $DestServer -and $SrcServer -notmatch $DestServer ){
            $DESTINATION = $site.server
            $Street = $site.street
            $POBox = $site.POBox
            $city = $site.City
            $State = $site.state
            $Zip = $site.zip
            $Country = $site.country
            $OfficePhone = $site.OfficePhone                
            $TargetOU = $site.TargetOU
            $Udrive = $site.Udrive + "$username$"
            $Sharelocalpath = $site.Sharelocalpath + $Username
            $NewSiteGroup = $site.NewSiteGroup
            $NewDFSGroup = $site.NewDFSGroup
            $DESTINATION
            Remove-ADGroupMember -server $DC -Identity $OldSiteGroup -Members $username -Confirm:$false
            Remove-ADGroupMember -server $DC -Identity $OldDFSGroup -Members $username -Confirm:$false
            Add-ADGroupMember -server $DC -Identity $NewDFSRemote -Members $username -Confirm:$false
            Add-ADGroupMember -server $DC -Identity $NewSiteGroup -Members $username -Confirm:$false
            Add-ADGroupMember -server $DC -Identity $NewDFSGroup -Members $username -Confirm:$false            
            }  
 }
```

My dropdownarray have the same value on both dropdown. But depending of my selection my var are going to change. thanks for helping.
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a dirty example. Replace both your forms with this. You have to fill in the commands again since I just extracted one of your forms to modify it. It's pretty basic modifications if you just read the code. Or you could used the software(primalforms) that you used to design this with(since you don't understand the code) to make it.

```
$DropDownArray = @("Test1", "Test2", "Test3")

# Form building

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 300
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = ”User move Destination Location”
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$DropDownFrom = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDownFrom.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,10)
$DropDownFrom.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
    $DropDownFrom.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownFrom)

$DropDownFromLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownFromLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$DropDownFromLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
$DropDownFromLabel.Text = "Select the user Original location ?"
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownFromLabel)


$DropDownTo = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDownTo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,50)
$DropDownTo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
    $DropDownTo.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownTo)

$DropDownToLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownToLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,50)
$DropDownToLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40)
$DropDownToLabel.Text = "Select the user Destination location ?"
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownToLabel)


$OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,100)
$OKButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({
$Form.DialogResult = "OK"
$Form.close()
})
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)


$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,130)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({
$Form.DialogResult = "Cancel"
$Form.close()
})
$Form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})

$result = $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Hi Grainmer, During the weekend I played with that script and I finally get use to the "windows" sinzing and all that stuff. I can't tell that I'm a master but it's true when they say that playing with code will help you learn it. I've started Powershell less then one month ago. Thanks for your help this one was a bit simple afterward. Have a nice week